# Any downfall (or better alternative) to run initialization code (HTTPHandler - URL association) using a static constructor?

Tags: c#, asp.net, httphandler

**Summary :**

I have a DLL that hosts a class library. The library is used by an ASP.NET website. I need some code (initialization) to be run when the library is used. I have placed the code on the static constructor of one of the classes, which most likely will be used. It runs right now, but I was wondering

1. is there a better place to put this code? Some sort of DLL init
   method?
2. are there any downfalls? If the class is never used, will the code
   run anyways?

Details:

I have a DLL that hosts a class library that implements ECommerce to be used on ASP.NET websites. It contains controls and logic objects specific to my client. As part of it, it contains an HTTPhandler that handles AJAX calls to the library. The url that is associated with the Handler has to be registered. I have done this on the static constructor of one of the classes.

```
 using System.Web.Routing;

 class CMyClass {
    static CMyClass() {
        RouteTable.Routes.Insert(0, new Route("myapi/{*pathinfo}", new CMyHTTPHandlerRouter()));
    }
}
```

This works right now. The site that uses the DLL does not have to register the route, which is very convenient. I was wondering, though:

1. is there a better place to register routes from a DLL? Or a better
   way to associate a handler with a URL, directly from the DLL, so it
   is always registered when the DLL is used.
2. are there any downfalls? If CMyClass  is never used, will the code run anyways?

Comment: You could create a simple configuration class inside your DLL and call a method on that class from global.asax when your site starts

Comment: That is exactly why we have global.asax and an Application_Start event...

Comment: Yes. I had it there (global.asax) but then if the consumer of the DLL forgets to call the method, then the URL never gets registered. I don't have a global.asax on the DLL. It is just a bunch of classes. Is there a similar thing to global.asax on a DLL? That would be helpful.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2):

I can answer your second question: the static constructor will only run if you somehow interact with CMyClass.  In other words, it's run on demand, not eagerly when you e.g. access the DLL.

Answer (score 0):

Routes are to be construed as "application code". Meaning once it is "compiled" you cannot make changes to it. This is by design. Application_Start is the place where routes are normally registered.

I would normally abide by this convention. But my reusable logic (i.e. inside any publicly exposed method in the dll) should ensure that the routes are registered, else throw up an error. This is how the end developers know that they aren't using your component right. And if "it" knows the routes are registered it can safely go and execute the actual stuff.

I'd use a static boolean variable to accomplish that.

```
public class MyMvcSolution
{
    public static bool Registered {get; set; }
    static MyMvcSolution(){ Registered = false; }

    public static void DoSomethingImportant()
    {
        if(Registered)
        {
            //do important stuff
        }
        else
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Whoa, routes are not registered!");
    }

    //this should be called in the Application_Start
    public static void Init()
    {
        RouteTable.Routes.Insert(0, new Route("myapi/{*pathinfo}", new CMyHTTPHandlerRouter()));
        Registered = true;
    }
}
```

I believe the above solution will kind of do.

There is an alternative strategy. We want to add routes "dynamically". [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6837420/145682) talks about forcing the BuildManager to register routes you mention is a `.cs` file. This file isn't "compiled" as part of the application; there will be a `*.cs` file in your application somewhere. You will make an assembly out of it on-the-fly, and from that force the buildmanager to register. There is also a mechanism to "edit" the routes once that file changes too. I'll leave it to you to explore this. Deep but interesting stuff.